# Python ValueError while attempting a dictionary based logging configuration

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to code a dictionary based logging configuration and have been stumped by a ValueError that occurs when I run the program. I've stripped it down to the essentials and the problem remains. I've read the 3.5 docs, logging HOWTO, Logging Cookbook, etc. but unfortunately, the solution has not presented itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I'm only 3 weeks into python so I may just be out of my depth at this point. Here's the code...

```
import logging.config

log_config = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters':{
        'verbose_formatter':{
            'format':'%(levelname)s: %(name)s: %(asctime)s.%(msecs).03d : '\
            '%(message)s: %(process)s: %(processName)s',
            'datefmt':'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        'precise_formatter':{
            'format':'%(levelname)s: %(name)s: %(asctime)s.%(msecs).03d : '\
            '%(message)s',
            'datefmt':'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        'brief_formatter':{
            'format':'%(levelname)s: %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers':{
        'con_handler':{
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'formatter':'precise_formatter',
            'stream':'ext://sys.stdout'
        },
        'file_handler':{
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename':'logger.log',
            'maxBytes':1048576,
            'backupCount':4,
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'formatter':'precise_formatter',
            'encoding':'utf8'
        }
    },
    'loggers':{
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'handlers':['con_handler', 'file_handler']
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(log_config)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.critical('This should always be seen!')
```

When run, I receive the follow:

```
ValueError was unhandled by user code
Message: Unable to configure logger 'handlers': 'ConvertingList' object has no attribute 'get'
```

or sometimes this...

```
ValueError was unhandled by user code
Message: Unable to configure logger 'level': 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I suspect that the different errors may have to do with the sometimes changing order of the dictionary?

Comment: Just a guess, but try specifying a list of dicts instead of a dict of dicts as the `handlers` value. Sounds like the logger is iterating over them, getting the dictionary keys and trying to call 'get' on them. If you change it to a list of dicts, it'll get a dict instead, and this dict will have a 'get' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the loggers section to

```
'loggers':{
    '': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'handlers':['con_handler', 'file_handler']
        }
}
```

The '' (empty string) refers to the root logger. you can add more loggers for different components:

```
'loggers':{
    '': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'handlers':['con_handler', 'file_handler']
        }
    'bottle': { #I only want error level from bottle :)
        'level':'ERROR',
        'handlers':['con_handler', 'file_handler']
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This did work for me.

I'll mention here that I'm troubled that I can't find anything (empty string referring to the root logger) like this in the examples shown in the logging docs, how to & cookbook. I'll assume (never a good idea right?) that this is just a condition that I'm too new to see plainly.

Comment: @Babaghanoush - I guess that normally you should not set the root logger at all since you should set the loggers you need by their names

Answer (score 0):

To config the `root` logger use a `root` key of your `log_config` dictionary.

> root - this will be the configuration for the root logger.

Source: [Dictionary Schema Details](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details)

Following this description your config should look something like this:

```
log_config = {

   ...
    'handlers': {
        'con_handler': ...,
        'file_handler': ...
    },
    'loggers': {
        'other_logger': ...
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['con_handler', 'file_handler']
    }
}
```